# rosdep has unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, apt, python, dependencies, ros

My synaptic manager gives me an error saying that python-rosdep is broken in my system. So I did the following: Edit->Fix broken packages->Apply. But I get an error:

```
 E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.10-100_all.deb: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.2-1_all.deb: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.2-100_all.deb: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal
```

If I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, that too gives me errors

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb (--unpack):

subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.10-100_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.10-100_all.deb (--unpack):

subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.2-1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.2-1_all.deb (--unpack):

subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.2-100_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.2-100_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:

/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.10-100_all.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.2-1_all.deb

/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.2-100_all.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Because of this problem I am not able to install anything via apt-get because of the error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies: 
python-rosdep : Depends: python-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.0) but 0.3.9-100 is to be installed`. 
Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also, the output of `apt-cache policy python-rosdep python-catkin-pkg` is

```
python-rosdep:
Installed: 0.15.0-1
Candidate: 0.15.0-1
Version table:
*** 0.15.0-1 0
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

python-catkin-pkg:
Installed: 0.3.9-100
Candidate: 0.4.10-100
Version table:
0.4.10-100 0
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
*** 0.3.9-100 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: A quick search of `python-catkin-pkg` shows it's available for later releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-catkin-pkg&searchon=names), but not 14.04 (trusty), and >4.0.0 rule implies later than 18.04 (bionic) - so I would check your sources for non-trusty. I would look there (you haven't provided, maybe you could `apt-cache policy python-rosdep python-catkin-pkg` & provide that...

Comment: The output is `python-rosdep:
  Installed: 0.15.0-1
  Candidate: 0.15.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.15.0-1 0
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python-catkin-pkg:
  Installed: 0.3.9-100
  Candidate: 0.4.10-100
  Version table:
     0.4.10-100 0
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.3.9-100 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: Please add additional info to your question. It can be edited there (and there are many formatting options, {} is correct for formatted text such as that copied from terminal output), but we can help you if you're having trouble with your question (not comments though)

Comment: @guiverc I have made the edits

Comment: Your first pasted message is *E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2* which is the final summary; the actual error message was above that in the listing/report; have a look and see what that says (ie. the message that generated the exit-status-2 that was repeated on that line)  Thanks for adding info on source - it's non-Ubuntu which I don't know.

Comment: The four 'giving up' errors indicate two possibilities: 1) That your packages, wherever you got them from, are badly made, or 2) That your five-year-old version of dpkg cannot handle some newer format within the packages. The easiest way to determine which is correct is to ask whatever non-Ubuntu source you got those packages from. You are correct that apt will (correctly) refuse to do anything useful until you either solve that package puzzle or remove the non-functional packages entirely. Apt is not broken. ROS tends to be easier to install on newer releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: I had messed up something in ros.. so I reinstalled it yesterday after which I got these errors. Since ros packages are standard.. I think it's the older version of dpkg that's causing the error. Can I upgrade dpkg?